# FAST_READ with ACR1255U

Tags: ios, nfc, apdu, acr122

I'm currently using this NFC reader [ACR1255](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/403/acr1255u-j1-secure-bluetooth%C2%AE-nfc-reader/) to reads NTAG213 with an text ndef on it on an iOS app
I'm currently doing 2 read commands for 16 bytes each (because i know the size of my ndef message) but i find it not really reliable
While reading the [NTAG213 doc](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf) I found the FAST_READ command but I can't seem to use it ?
I'm kinda new at NFC and it's a pretty mess for me I'm not sure i'm doing something wrong ?

For the moment i'm sending this apdu to read: "FF B0 00 04 10" and "FF B0 00 04 10" and concat the result and I got my ndef message
But for the FAST_READ I try this : "FF 3A 04 00 00" and I receive "6A 81" for function not supported.

Is there a protocol compatibily I didn't see ? Or someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your end index is incorrect, it should be 4 or more.

Working [example](https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api/blob/85cbccfbb503861898d6d6b6ab840176ceed9ef5/tools/src/main/java/org/nfctools/mf/ul/ntag/NfcNtag.java#L69).